# Inno Setup - Defining a default path inside [code]

Tags: function, inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm trying to read the Windows Registry so my app updates can retrieve the previously saved instalation path as its DefaultDirName.

I've read somewhere that I should call a function, like:

```
DefaultDirName="{code:GetPath}"
```

The problem is that I need to define a default path, in case the function does not find a previous one. For instance, 'C:\MyPath'. So I did this:

```
[Code]
function GetPath(Value: String): String;
var
  OrigPath: string;
begin
  Result := '{sd}\MyPath';
  if RegQueryStringValue(HKCU, 'Software\MyApp', 'PathExec', OrigPath) then
     Result := OrigPath;
end;
```

That is not working. When I run the setup, at the destination dir dialog I'm getting literally "C:\PathOfMySetup\{sd}\MyPath", not "C:\MyPath".

What should I write at that first "Result := " line in order to "MyPath" be created at the System Drive?

Thanks.

Comment: How can there be a `HKCU` registry key for your application, if you are only installing the application?

Comment: Isn't that the purpose of the first Result, to act as a default? If the RegQueryStringValue fails to find the key, the function will return my C:\MyPath to fill the dir dialog, right?

Comment: But the `DefaultDirName` is the default installation path for new installations. When re-installing/upgrading, the value is not used (by default). So your code actually does not make sense to me. You would get the same behavior with simple `DefaultDirName={sd}\MyPath`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constants in Pascal Script are not magically expanded. You have to expand them explicitly using the [`ExpandConstant` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_expandconstant):

```pascal
Result := ExpandConstant('{sd}\MyPath');
```

Comment: Thanks!! That fixed the problem.